# deducing types of would-be-called overloaded constructor

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, c++17, stdtuple

Given a type, say `A` and some arguments, say `1, 4.2`, I want to find the constructor of `A` that can be called with these types. Due to conversions, the types may be different. I.e. instead of the passed `int, double`, the signature may be `unsigned int, float` and this is what I'm after. As an extra twist: the constructor will be overloaded, i.e. there's not just one to consider.

For some context: The reason is that I want to store the arguments in a `std::tuple` and then store that in a `std::any`. Later on to get the `tuple` out of the `any`, I must know the type that was stored. At that point (within `A` e.g.), I only know the types `unsigned int, float`.

Here is an example on godbolt that shows this issue above in `A`. Additionally, a class `B` takes a `std::shared_ptr<Base>` but I want to create the tuple/any from a `std::shared_ptr<Child>`...

https://godbolt.org/z/RB8UCR

So far, we only came across https://gist.githubusercontent.com/deni64k/c5728d0596f8f1640318b357701f43e6/raw/87ea05a8f7b3f6add5b3775fecf089e0aa421492/reflection.hxx which goes into the right direction. But it's not possible to compile this code on Windows: https://godbolt.org/z/TAk7Dy

Has anyone come across this problem before and knows a C++17 cross-platform solution to it?

Comment: You might look at [`magic_get`](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get).

Comment: Will the various instances of this deferred initialization for one class all use the same constructor?  If not, how will you communicate which tuple type to fetch?

Comment: currently there's two ctors: One for deserialization taking a std::any which holds the tuple. And then the other that can be used to construct the type directly, and should be looked at to define the type of the tuple.